# using freemarker with javascript ES6 Template Strings

Tags: javascript, freemarker, template-engine

Freemaker templates render variables with the following syntax:  ${name}

Javascript ES6 template strings have a similar syntax ${name}

The problem is that when freemarker runs on the server, it will try to render the templates in the javascript code, because Freemarker thinks that it has encountered a variable (when in fact it is a javascript template that should be rendered on the client).  Recommnedation on how to handle this?

One way is to wrap all the JS in a freemarker comment (so it is never evaluated),

or put the JS code in a seprate file (not inlined in the html page) so that it is never evaluated by freemarker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** Since FreeMarker 2.3.28 you can configure FreeMarker to use `[=exp]` instead of `${exp}`, by setting the `interpolation_syntax` configuration setting to `square_bracket` (in the Java API: `Configuration cfg; ... cfg.setInterpolationSyntax(Configuration.SQUARE_BRACKET_INTERPOLATION_SYNTAX)`). Then `${exp}` is just static text for FreeMarker. Do not confuse this setting with the `tag_syntax` setting, which also can have `square_bracket` value, but is independent of the interpolation syntax (but you may prefer setting both to `square_bracket`). See also: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_alternativesyntax.html

**Outdated answer:** FreeMarker's syntax is not configurable unfortunately (nor is the ES6 template syntax, I assume). Because that would be the real solution, to configure it to use something else instead of `$`. You can create a poor man's implementation of that with a custom `TemplateLoader` implementation that just delegates to another `TemplateLoader`, except that it adds a filter to the `Reader` it returns, and with that it modifies the template on-the-fly. It would replace `${`-s with `$<#-- -->{`, and `@{`-s with `${`. So then your original template can be something like `${forES6} @{forFM}`. This have quite a few drawbacks, like the column numbers in FreeMarker error positions will be displaced, and the Eclipse plugin and some other tools won't work.

Answer (score 10):

you can use javascripts in noparse tags

```
 <#noparse>...</#noparse>
```

or

```
const name = "WORLD";
Hello ${r"${name}"}
```

html view "Hello ${name}" output-> Hello WORLD

Answer (score 2):

If you use [<#include>](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_include.html) to include html files with embedded es6 scripts inside, you might also stumble upon es6 template parsing issues. The simple solution to fix this is using `parse=false` option:

```
<#include "/path/to/file.html" parse=false>
```